# Apache Solr with Hibernate-Java or with Ms SQL Server

Tags: java, hibernate, solr

I have Problem with SQl server Performance because of Heavy Calculation query,
so we decided that we put Solr as intermediate and index all data from either Hibernate or Direct from SQl server,

so can anybody suggest/help me that it is possible ?
please suggest any tutorial link for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) to transfer data, which you can schedule using [DataImportScheduler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Scheduling).

I had the similar problem where SQL Server SP took 12 hours to update relationships between objects (rows), so we ended up using [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) (open source graph database), which exactly matched our data model.

We needed object relationships to be reflected in Solr searches, e.g. give me all objects whose name starts with "obj" and whose parent is of type "typ".